# Bootstrap loads but doesnt apply styles

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am loading up and using bootstrap like this, but the styles are not actually being applied to my `row` and `col` divs. In my network monitor I can see the css is being successfully loaded, yet for some reason it just isnt doing anything. Really stumped here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="name" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label for="number">Number</label>
        <input id="number" />
    </div>
</div>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Number</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

I changed my link to use Bootstrap 4 and it still isnt working

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Add a table class to your table as well as following the advice in the answers below - <table class="table">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="number">Number</label>
        <input id="number" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="number">Number</label>
        <input id="number" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <label for="number">Number</label>
        <input id="number" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Maybe I'm wrong but with my experience in bootstrap you have the specify the screen size when you're using the column features.  Just use medium when you're building something that should fit across all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong CSS class names. You are loading a bootstrap 3.x version, and it uses different classes for different device resolutions:

- If you want a block that occupies 4 columns, you need to use `col-xs-4` for extra-small devices (<768px width), `col-sm-4` for small, `col-md-4` for medium size and `col-lg-4` for large devices (>1200px).

You may check the documentation at: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options